# Controlling style of children controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to create a transparent button with image and text. I have a DockPanel inside a button, with Image and TextBlock controls. When mouse is over it, it should create some zoom on the image, and also make some effect (ex glow) on TextBlock text.

Is there a way I can have one style only, for button, in which I can also specify style for image and TextBlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can nest styles, e.g.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```